# eclipse build path error

Tags: java, eclipse, configuration

eclipse say me:
[image]

[image]

I click to quick fix and make so:

[image]

after it I see old error.

How to fix this problem?

**UPDATE**

project structure:

[image]

Comment: How does the source folder structure look like?

Comment: please read my update

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you select correct src path in eclipse. right click your project and go to Java Build Path to check the source folders on build path.
2. Go to project menu, clear and rebuild you project.
3. Restart you eclipse.
4. Delete eclipse

Comment: I tryed this steps before